# Can't Find Driver for HP Deskjet 712c Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, printer, print-drivers, hp-deskjet

The instructions on HP's website indicate that this driver comes with Windows XP and does not need to be downloaded. I have the original CD that came with the printer, but that fails saying it is not compatible with Windows XP.

Every other manual way I try to add the printer, at some point asks me to insert the Windows XP CD to complete the process. I purchased this computer from a surplus at my place of employment and do not have the disc. I have searched everywhere to try and find a downloadable version of the driver.

Is there any other way to get this printer working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the PCL 6 HP Universal Print driver for XP here: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3271558&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=228

This will make the basic functions of 90% of HP's range of printers work. It's worth a shot. It will not include some of the advanced features that may be available with your printer, but if it works, it'll allow you to print, which is better than nothing.